# Scala IDE 3.0.4 editor support for html and sbt

Tags: eclipse, scala, playframework-2.0, sbt, typesafe

I recently installed the Scala IDE Eclipse Kepler, and I have trouble with scala.html template files and sbt files.

The other references online say that I can use "Template Editor" to edit the scala template. However, such template is not found in the IDE.

I also don't see any mentioning of the editor for .sbt files.

IntelliJ Idea has them all, but requires a fee.

Is there anything that I should install to edit all files related to scala and play framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Play plugin for 2.11 (it seems you are using 2.11) is only available together with the 4.0 milestone 3 release, available here:

http://scala-ide.org/download/milestone.html

Unfortunately, the changes we needed to make in order to adapt to 2.11 made it too difficult to re-release it on 3.0.4. I hope the milestone release is good for you. We should have the next major release soon, though.